# Why Java 9 collection factory have separate methods for each argument when it have varargs supported

Tags: java, collections, java-9

In Java 9 `List` ,`Set` and `Map` interface we have  `of` method which support varargs (`static <E> List<E> of(E... elements)`), so what's the purpose of having separate methods having arguments one to ten.

```
static <E> List<E> of(E e1) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing one elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing two elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing three elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing four elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing five elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing six elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing seven elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing eight elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8, E e9) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing nine elements.
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8, E e9, E e10) //Returns an unmodifiable list containing ten elements.
```

To create a list with more than three element's the `List.of` method which support varargs , is calling `new ImmutableCollections.ListN<>(elements);`. This is also same for `List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3)` to `List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3,....E e10)`.

Implementation of `List.of` method which support varargs

```
static <E> List<E> of(E... elements) {
    switch (elements.length) { // implicit null check of elements
        case 0:
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            var list = (List<E>) ImmutableCollections.EMPTY_LIST;
            return list;
        case 1:
            return new ImmutableCollections.List12<>(elements[0]);
        case 2:
            return new ImmutableCollections.List12<>(elements[0], elements[1]);
        default:
            return new ImmutableCollections.ListN<>(elements);
    }
}
```

Implementation of `List.of` method which support 10 elements.

```
static <E> List<E> of(E e1, E e2, E e3, E e4, E e5, E e6, E e7, E e8, E e9, E e10) {
    return new ImmutableCollections.ListN<>(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5,
                                            e6, e7, e8, e9, e10);
}
```

Comment: @ernest_k Its talking about performance while using varargs method, but still methods with three to 10 parameters is calling another varargs method ie, ImmutableCollections.ListN(E... input).

Comment: You should write the consideration into your question instead of adding it as a comment. Otherwise, your question is just a duplicate.

Comment: The first comment to the linked question could be of your interest specifically.